# python negative look behind

Tags: python

Is there a way to scan an entire text document and say find everything that says "lol" and replace it with the id value of the first previous chapter tag? maybe something like this.

python

```
x=open('source.txt')
lines = x.readlines()
for line in lines:
  if line.startswith('<text'):
    line.replace('lol', first previous chapter id value)
x.write(lines)
x.close()
```

source text

```
<chapter id="1">
<text class="lol">
<text class="lol">
<chapter id="2">
<text class="lol">
<text class="lol">
<chapter id="3">
<text class="lol">
<text class="lol">
<chapter id="4">
<text class="lol">
<text class="lol">
```

result text

```
<chapter id="1">
<text class="1">
<text class="1">
<chapter id="2">
<text class="2">
<text class="2">
<chapter id="3">
<text class="3">
<text class="3">
<chapter id="4">
<text class="4">
<text class="4">
```

Comment: By the way, this is not actually a negative lookbehind, just a lookbehind.  Actually, it's not even really a lookbehind unless you're using regex.

Comment: Is this specifically for HTML, or is it for generalized look-behinds with HTML as an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that. Basically all you needed to do extra was find that chapter id. Also I'm assuming you know to write to file, hence why I just printed each line.

```
import re
with open('source.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        if line.startswith('<chapter'):
                id = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', line) #Grabs string between matching quotations
        if line.startswith('<text'):
                line = line.replace('lol',id[0])
        print line[:-1]
```

Output:

```
<chapter id="1">
<text class="1">
<text class="1">
<chapter id="2">
<text class="2">
<text class="2">
<chapter id="3">
<text class="3">
<text class="3">
<chapter id="4">
<text class="4">
<text class="4">
```

Comment: The only thing I'd add (perhaps unnecessarily) would be making the regex a bit more explicit, such as `id = re.findall(r'id="([^\"]*)", line)` and then adding a bit more to the replace, perhaps `line = line.replace('"lol"', '"{%s}"' % (id[0]))`. This may be overkill though - your solution works fine :)

Comment: Might also show him how to use a context to open the file `with open('file') as f` ...

Comment: @RocketDonkey Yeah, I felt like it shouldn't be that neccessary. Your solution is more through though.

Comment: @alan please see my edits. I was just trying to keep it as close as to the original.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu +1 (You beat me by two minutes :)